# Why are only 10 of my 16 posts being shown?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

So I am making a website and ran into a problem of a custom post type being shown. Basically, I have a post type called resource. The resources are sorted into three different categories, For Stats, For Non-Stats, and Clinical.

Here is what the resource post editing page looks like. [image: resource post editing]
As you can see, at the bottom there is a dropdown menu at the bottom for the user to decide the audience. Here is the code I'm using to sort the resources on the resource page into the individual sections.

```
<?php $args = array(
'post_type' => 'resource',
'order'     => 'ASC');
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );       
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
    $resource_type = get_field('resource_type');
    $audience = get_field('audience');
    $forStat = "For Statisticians";
    $notForStat = "For Non-Statisticians";
    $clinical = "Clinical Trials";
    $hasLink = FALSE;
    if (get_field(resource_link)){
        $hasLink = TRUE;
        $resource_link = get_field('resource_link');
    } else {
        $resource = get_field('resource');
    }
    ?>

    <?php if ($audience == $forStat) { ?>

        <?php if ($hasLink) { ?>
            <a href="<?php echo $resource_link; ?>"><button type="button" class="list-group-item"><?php the_title(); ?></button></a>
        <?php } else { 
            $resourceUrl = $resource['url']; ?>
            <a href="<?php echo $resourceUrl; ?>"><button type="button" class="list-group-item"><?php the_title(); ?></button></a>
        <?php } ?>

    <?php } ?>

<?php endwhile;?>
```

Here is the resource page so you can see that only 10 posts are being shown even though there are 16 resources For Statisticians. [The website resource page.](http://websitescientist.com/testingSite/wordpress/resources/)

Any ideas why only the first 10 resources that I made are being shown?

Comment: How you (or your framework)  manage pagination  ..  ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add

```
'posts_per_page' => -1,
```

as a parameter.

```
$args = array(
  'post_type' => 'resource',
  'order'     => 'ASC',
  'posts_per_page' => -1
);
```